# GAE TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, google-app-engine, typeerror

I'm trying to write my first app in Google App Engine with Python. Here the link of the app: http://contractpy.appspot.com/ - it's just an experimental app. The entire code is bellow.

But I'm getting this error (showed on logs):

```
(...) line 229, in post "owner":owner})
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Line 229 is in this if block:

```
if (resident_name and valid_resident(resident_name)) \
        and (user_SSN and valid_SSN(user_SSN)) \
        and ((not user_email) or (user_email and valid_email(user_email))):
            self.redirect('/welcome?resident=%s&nacionality=%s?SSN=%s?driverLicense=%s?email=%s?witness =%s?owner=%s' % {"resident":resident_name,
                                      "nacionality":user_nacionality,
                                      "SSN":user_SSN,
                                      "driverLicense":user_driverLicense,
                                      "email":user_email,
                                      "witness ":witness ,
                                      "owner":owner})
```

More specificaly, it's this line:

```
"owner":owner})
```

I tried to make changes, read similar awnswers, but nothing worked. 
Can someone figure out what is causing this error?
Thanks in advance for any help!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright 2007 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

import webapp2

form = """

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .label {text-align: right}
      .error {color: red}
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Signup</h2>
    <form method="post">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="label">
            resident
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="resident" value= "%(resident)s">
          </td>
          <td class="error"> %(resident_error)s

          </td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
          <td class="label">
            nacionality
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="nacionality" value= " ">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="label">
            License
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="driverLicense" value="">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="label">
            SSN
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="SSN" value="%(SSN)s">
          </td>
          <td class="error"> %(SSN_error)s
          </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td class="label">
            Email (optional)
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="%(email)s">
          </td>
          <td class="error"> %(email_error)s

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

<br>
        <td class="label">
          Contract Type
          <select name = "contractType">
              <option>House  Rental Contract</option>
              <option>Car Rental Contract</option>
              <option>Other</option>
          </select>
          </td>
<br>
<br>

<br>
          owner
          <select name = "owner">
              <option>House owner</option>
              <option>Car owner</option>
              <option>Other owner</option>
          </select>
<br>
<br>

<br>
          Witness
          <select name = "witness">
              <option>Carl Sagan</option>
              <option>Mahatma Gandhi</option>
          </select>
<br>
<br>

      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
"""

welcome = """
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Unit 2 Signup</title>
  </head>

  <body>

%(contractType)s

In consideration of the agreements of the Resident(s), known as: %(resident)s The owner hereby rents them the dwelling located at %(residentAdress)s, for the period commencing on the %(dateStarts)s, and monthly thereafter until the last day of %(dateEnds)s, at which time this Agreement is terminated. Resident(s), in consideration of owners permitting them to occupy the above property, hereby agrees to the following terms:

RENT: To pay as rental the sum of $ (rentalSum) per month, due and payable in advance from the first day of every month. Failure to pay rent when due will result in the owner taking immediate legal action to evict the Resident from the premises and seize the security deposit.
LATE FEE: Rent received after the first of the month will be subject to a late fee of 10% plus (3.00) dollars per day.

ACCEPTED THIS (dateContract), at (localContract).

___________________________________________________
%(resident)s - Resident

___________________________________________________
%(owner)s – owner

___________________________________________________
%(witness)s – Witness

  </body>
</html>

"""

import re

USER_RE = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}$")
def valid_resident(resident):
    return USER_RE.match(resident)

PASS_RE = re.compile(r"^.{3,20}$")
def valid_SSN(SSN):
    return PASS_RE.match(SSN)

EMAIL_RE = re.compile(r"^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$")
def valid_email(email):
    return EMAIL_RE.match(email)

def escape_html(s):
    for (i,o) in (("&","&"), (">",">"), ("<","<"), ('"','"')):
        s = s.replace(i,o)
        return s

import time

import datetime

def dateToday():
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    todayDay = str(today.day)
    todayMonth = str(today.month)
    monthExt = {'1':' January ', '2':'February', '3':' March ', '4':'April', '5':'May', '6':'June', '7 ':' July ', '8':'August', '9':'September', '10':'October', '11':'November ', '12':'December'}
    todayYear = str(today.year)
    return(todayDay + ' of  ' + monthExtenso[todaymonth] + ' of ' + todayYear)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
       self.response.out.write(form %{"resident": "",
                                       "SSN": "",
                                       "driverLicense": "",
                                       "email":"",
                                       "resident_error": "",
                                       "SSN_error": "",
                                       "driverLicense_error": "",
                                       "email_error": ""})

    def write_form(self, text_write):
       self.response.out.write(text_write)

    def post(self):
        resident_name = self.request.get(escape_html("resident"))
        user_nacionality = self.request.get("nacionality")
        user_SSN = self.request.get(escape_html('SSN'))
        user_email = self.request.get(escape_html('email'))
        user_driverLicense = self.request.get(escape_html('driverLicense'))
        resident_error = ""
        SSN_error = ""
        driverLicense_error = ""
        contract_type = self.request.get("contractType")
        owner = self.request.get("owner")
        witness  = self.request.get("witness ")

        if (resident_name and valid_resident(resident_name)) \
        and (user_SSN and valid_SSN(user_SSN)) \
        and ((not user_email) or (user_email and valid_email(user_email))):
            self.redirect('/welcome?resident=%s&nacionality=%s?SSN=%s?driverLicense=%s?email=%s?witness =%s?owner=%s' % {"resident":resident_name,
                                      "nacionality":user_nacionality,
                                      "SSN":user_SSN,
                                      "driverLicense":user_driverLicense,
                                      "email":user_email,
                                      "witness":witness,
                                      "owner":owner})
        else:
            if not valid_resident(resident_name):
                resident_error = "Oh no!!! this resident name isn't valid!"
            if not valid_SSN(user_SSN):
                SSN_error = "Oh no!!! SSN isn't valid!"
            if user_email and not valid_email(user_email):
                email_error = "Oh no!!! e-mail isn't valid!"
            self.write_form(form % {"resident":resident_name,
                                      "resident_error":resident_error,
                                      "SSN":user_SSN,
                                      "SSN_error":SSN_error,
                                      "driverLicense":user_driverLicense,
                                      "email":user_email,
                                      })

class WelcomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        geted_resident_name = self.request.get('resident')
        geted_user_nacionality = self.request.get("nacionality")
        geted_user_SSN = self.request.get('SSN')
        geted_user_email = self.request.get('email')
        geted_user_driverLicense = self.request.get('driverLicense')
        geted_resident_error = ""
        geted_SSN_error = ""
        geted_driverLicense_error = ""
        #geted_contract_type = self.request.get("contractType")
        geted_owner = self.request.get("owner")
        geted_witness  = self.request.get("witness ")



        self.response.out.write(welcome % {"resident":geted_resident_name,
                                      "nacionality":geted_user_nacionality,
                                      "SSN":geted_user_SSN,
                                      "SSN_error":geted_SSN_error,
                                      "driverLicense":geted_user_driverLicense,
                                      "email":geted_user_email,
                                      "witness ":geted_witness ,
                                      "owner":geted_owner,
                                      })


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler), ('/welcome', WelcomeHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right hand argument to the `%` operator when used for string formatting must be a tuple, not a dict. In your case, the dict will replace the first occurrence of `%s` in the format string, leaving not enough other objects to replace the others. You'll need to manually build a tuple of the items you want to use for replacement, like:

```
('/welcome?resident=%s&nacionality=%s?SSN=%s?driverLicense=%s?email=%s?witness =%s?
owner=%s' % (resident_name, user_nacionality, user_SSN, user_driverLicense, user_email,
witness, owner)
```

Comment: Interesting... I used another working model app where I thought was used a dictionary. But your sugestion fixed the error. Thanks, Wooble!

Answer (score 1):

not enough arguments is caused when you have x format parameters in the string but you only passed y arguments to match then (where x > y).

In your case, you have a miss %, just change s% to %s.

```
self.redirect('/welcome?resident=%s&nacionality=%s?SSN=%s?driverLicense=%s?email=s%?witness =%s?owner=%s' % {"resident":resident_name,
                                      "nacionality":user_nacionality,
                                      "SSN":user_SSN,
                                      "driverLicense":user_driverLicense,
                                      "email":user_email,
                                      "witness ":witness ,
                                      "owner":owner})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Shay. There was really a typping error ("email=s%"). But I fixed that (%s) and the message error persist. Any tip what is going wrong?